# finding document in mongodb with specific id and username

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

```
{
    "data": [
        {
          "_id": 555,
          "username": "jackson",
          "status": "i am coding",
          "comments": [
            {
              "user": "bob",
              "comment": "bob me "
            },
            {
              "user": "daniel",
              "comment": "bob the builder"
            },
            {
              "user": "jesus",
              "comment": "bob the builder"
            },
            {
              "user": "hunter",
              "comment": "bob the builder"
            },
            {
              "user": "jeo",
              "comment": "bob the builder"
            },
            {
              "user": "jill",
              "comment": "bob the builder"
            }
          ]
        }
    ]
}
```

so i want to get the result with `_id :555` and `user:bob` i tried with below code but i cant make it work it returns empty array

```
app.get('/all',function(req , res){
  db.facebook.find({_id:555},{comments:[{user:"bob"}]},function(err,docs){res.send(docs,{data:docs});});
} );
```

i want the result to be like this listed below with the comment with `user:bob`

```
{
    "_id": 555,
    "username": "jackson",
    "status": "i am coding",
    "comments": [
        {
        "user": "bob",
        "comment": "bob me "
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only aggregate or mapReduce could exclude items from subarray in output. Shortest is to use $redact:

```
db.facebook.aggregate({
 $redact:{
      $cond:{ 
         if:{$and:[{$not:"$username"},{$ne:["$user","bob"]}]}, 
         then: "$$PRUNE", 
         else: "$$DESCEND" 
      }
 }
})
```

**Explanation:**
`$reduct` would be applied to each subdocument starting from whole document. For each subdocument `$reduct` would either prune it or descend. We want to keep top level document, that is why we have `{$not:"$username"}` condition. It prevents top level document from pruning. On next level we have `comments` array. `$prune` would apply condition to each item of comments array. First condition `{$not:"$username"}` is true for all comments, and second condition `{$ne:["$user","bob"]}` is true for all subdocuments where user!="bob", so such documents would be pruned.

**Update:** in node.js with mongodb native driver

```
db.facebook.aggregate([{
 $redact:{
      $cond:{ 
         if:{$and:[{$not:"$username"},{$ne:["$user","bob"]}]}, 
         then: "$$PRUNE", 
         else: "$$DESCEND" 
      }
 }
}], function(err,docs){})
```

One more thing: `$prune` is new operator and available only in MongoDB 2.6

Comment: i cant understand this $redact can u explain this with normal feature

Comment: so where can i add my err function and result ? that is function(err,docs) {res.send{data:docs} } .